# Change color in barchart legend

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I successfully tested this code in order to change barchart columns color:

```
XYChart.Data<String, Number> dataS1 = new XYChart.Data<>();
            dataS1.nodeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Node>()
            {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Node> ov, Node oldNode, Node newNode)
                {
                    if (newNode != null)
                    {
                        if (dataS1.getYValue().intValue() > 8)
                        {
                            newNode.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: navy;");
                        }
                        else if (dataS1.getYValue().intValue() > 5)
                        {
                            newNode.setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: firebrick;");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

But it turns out that the color of the legend is not changed.
Is there any way to do this without using traditional CSS file? I would like to use the above approach if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have one single series, the legend will contain one single item.

If you change the color of the items in the chart based on some value, according to your conditions there will be three different colors.

This means you need to have three different items on the legend.

One possible approach will be using a different type of chart, like a LineChart, drawing a colored line for each bar. This has the problem that for every bar you create a new series, so the legend will contain as many items as series.

Other approach will be using a single series, but adding as many items as required to the legend.

Note that in both cases you have to deal with private API since `Legend` is not public, and as you know, this is not advisable since it may change at any time.

For the first approach have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818036/how-to-remove-legends-in-javafx-line-chart).

For the second one, this is a very simple working snippet:

```
@Override 
public void start(Stage stage) {
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    BarChart<String,Number> barChart = new BarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
    barChart.setTitle("Tricolored BarChart");
    yAxis.setLabel("Value");

    XYChart.Series<String,Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Item 1", 7.5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Item 2", 2.3));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Item 3", 8.5));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Item 4", 4.8));      
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Item 5", 13.5));      
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Item 6", 6.5));      

    Scene scene  = new Scene(barChart,600,400);
    barChart.getData().addAll(series1);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    series1.getData().forEach(d->
            d.getNode().setStyle("-fx-bar-fill: "
                    .concat(d.getYValue().floatValue()>8?"navy;":
                            d.getYValue().floatValue()>5?"firebrick;":"orange")));
    Legend legend = (Legend)barChart.lookup(".chart-legend");
    Legend.LegendItem li1=new Legend.LegendItem("Over 8", new Rectangle(10,4,Color.NAVY));
    Legend.LegendItem li2=new Legend.LegendItem("Over 5 up to 8", new Rectangle(10,4,Color.FIREBRICK));
    Legend.LegendItem li3=new Legend.LegendItem("Below 5", new Rectangle(10,4,Color.ORANGE));
    legend.getItems().setAll(li1,li2,li3);
}
```

And this will be the result:

[image: Legend]

Comment: beware (I know that you know, but for the sake of the OP and future readers :) changing the color of barChart data by their value is not what a barChart is meant for, users will most likely be confused!

Comment: @kleopatra can you propose some better solution?

Comment: I tested this solution but it's not working for StackedBarChart.

Comment: How are you going to paint the items on the chart on every stacked bar? The solution is not the same, for sure. This one works because you paint different bars.