# How to remove Legend of BarChart

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

How to remove Legend from BarChat.
I have some code.

```
float[] yData = { (float)Math.abs(item._Lent),(float) Math.abs( item._Barrow )};
    String[] xData = { "salary", "Spends" };
    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < yData.length; i++)
        entries.add(new BarEntry(yData[i], i));
    BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "");
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < xData.length; i++)
        labels.add(xData[i]);

    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
    mChart.setData(data); // set the data and list of lables into chart
    BarChart barchart = mChart;
    Legend legend = barchart.getLegend();
    legend.setEnabled(false);

    YAxis topAxis = barchart.getAxisLeft();
    topAxis.setDrawLabels(false);

    YAxis bottomAxis = barchart.getAxisRight();
    bottomAxis.setDrawLabels(false);

    XAxis rightAxis = barchart.getXAxis();
    rightAxis.setDrawLabels(false);
    bottomAxis.setDrawLabels(false);
```

`

This code not working properly. I gives me following out put.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6lKL.png)

Comment: And what output you want to receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set legend visible to false, like this:   `barchart.setLegendVisible(false);` - so your code will look something like this:

```
//rest of your code
    ....
BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
mChart.setData(data); // set the data and list of lables into chart
BarChart barchart = mChart;
barchart.setLegendVisible(false);
    ...
//more of your code...
```

Give it a try and let me know if it helps. You can also look at the selected answer to this closely related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983131/remove-javafx-2-linechart-legend-items).

Answer (score 3):

Hide the description with `setDescription("")` :

```
barchart.setDescription("");
```

Comment: Thanks , But I want to hide legend also.

Comment: your code works perfectly, run a minimal version of it with a plain activity. For me, only the description was left, legend is not visible. I use MpChart v2.2.3