# How to fix ugly spacing in JavaFX chart legend

Tags: java, css, javafx, charts, javafx-css

I have a JavaFX `LineChart`, and the spacing of the legend items is really awkward looking.

[image]

I want the item spacing to appear neater and more orderly. For example, possibly squeezing them together to make the legend size match their combined size.

How can I do this? I combed through the JavaFX CSS properties list pretty thoroughly, and I didn't see anything relevant that seemed to work.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46356513/230513).